# Не работает SQL запрос при добавлении AS

Tags: sql, postgresql

Запрос который работает

```
select analytics.public.client.name, analytics.public.client.whatsapp, analytics.public.incoming_request.utm_source
from client
inner join incoming_request
on client.id = incoming_request.client_id;
```

Добавил AS и этот же запрос перестал работать

```
select analytics.public.client.name, analytics.public.client.whatsapp, analytics.public.incoming_request.utm_source
from client as c
inner join incoming_request as ir
on c.id = ir.client_id
```

Ну вот как так???

Код ошибки

```
[42P01] ОШИБКА: в элементе предложения FROM неверная ссылка на таблицу "client" Подсказка: Возможно, предполагалась ссылка на псевдоним таблицы "c". Позиция: 8
```

Но там нет, я перепроверил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого случая даже [специальную отдельную подсказку](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_STABLE/src/backend/parser/parse_relation.c) выводим

```
 * If we found a match that has an alias and the alias is visible in the
 * namespace, then the problem is probably use of the relation's real name
 * instead of its alias, ie "SELECT foo.* FROM foo f". This mistake is
 * common enough to justify a specific hint.
```

Запрос вида

```
SELECT foo.column_name FROM foo as f
```

Ошибочен. Если вы пишете алиас - то и далее в запросе должны использовать этот алиас, т.е.

```
SELECT f.column_name FROM foo as f
```

Поскольку отношения `foo` более в дереве запроса нет, вы указали ему псевдоним.

PS: указывать имена полей, начиная с имени базы - довольно странная затея. Тогда уж и имена таблиц пишите так же, и все операторы тоже fully qualified, а то как-то непоследовательно.

Comment: "указывать имена полей, начиная с имени базы - довольно странная затея." Так у меня нет других вариантов. любой другой способ выдаёт ошибку

Comment: `select c.name from clients as c`